# test with Jmeter for consumer and producer

Tags: java, jms, jmeter

I have two programs, the first is a producer:

```
public class Producer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:12345");
        final Connection c = cf.createConnection();
        final Session s = c.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        final TextMessage msg = s.createTextMessage("rho " + new Date().toString());
        final MessageProducer p = s.createProducer(new ActiveMQQueue("rmannibucau"));
        p.send(msg);
        p.close();
        s.close();
        c.close();
        }
}
```

and the second is a consumer:

```
public class Listener {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:12345");
        final Connection c = cf.createConnection();
        final Session s = c.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        s.createConsumer(s.createQueue("rmannibucau")).setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            System.out.println(message.toString());
        }
    });

    c.start();
    s.run();
    }
}
```

I use ActiveMQ, java, jms and I want to test with Jmetter to know how much message consumer can consume in 1 minute, help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to create some sort of [Custom Java Sampler.](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html) When creating one of these, you can call your code from inside, set start/end timers, if the request was successful/failed etc. Then, you put this jar into JMeter and it will appear as a Java Sampler. From here, you can use all of JMeter's functionality to specify users, requests, time limit, etc.

I hope this is enough of a start to help you out.